# What is the terminology, UI name for readonly field value?

Tags: terminology, cards

What is the terminology of the following UI elements in this screenshot?

- `John Doe`
- `https://www.facebook.com/john.doe`
- `Principal: john.doe@gmail.com`
- ...

These UI elements are readonly field values; these values can be edited by the `Update` (`Modifier` in French) link button.

I looked for the right terminology to use in search engines, to find UX Design examples.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `readonly field` isn't a bad name for the individual elements.
People can refer to this as a `label` field or a `display` field.

Possibly as a higher level concept, the page itself could be a:

- readonly page
- information page
- display page

If you're looking for a way to describe the field and it's associated `update` function then I'd describe the field as `mode switching` - it has a `display` mode and an `edit` mode which you activate with the `update` link.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Material Design](https://material.io/components/text-fields/#theming) calls them "read-only fields" and that would be widely understood by UX designers and developers.

Answer (score 1):

Those are `labels` that are being replaced by textboxes when you click "Modify"
They are not `disabled` and they are not `readonly` textboxes